# using 2 different lines on the same chart

Tags: r

```
 df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 df6 <- aggregate(recovered ~ region, subset(df), sum)

 df4 <- aggregate(death ~ region, subset(df), sum)
```

How can I show the df6 and df4 data with different lines on the same chart.

with different lines on the line graph.

Comment: Your link to data does not work.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `subset(df)` in `aggregate` ?

Comment: region death and region recovered count  to be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a base R approach:

```
plotdf <- aggregate(cbind(recovered,death) ~ region, df, sum)
rownames(plotdf) <- plotdf$region
plotdf <- as.matrix(plotdf[,-1])
barplot(t(as.matrix(plotdf)), beside = TRUE, col = c("green","red"))
legend("topleft",c("Recovered","Died"), fill = c("green","red"))
```

[image]

And here's the (better?) "tidyverse" way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(recovered = sum(recovered),
            death = sum(death)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-region) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = region, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  labs(x = "Region", y = "Number", fill = "Status")
```

[image]